# XSL : XML to CSV transformation, parse an attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

I am converting an XML file into a CSV file in XSLT 3.0, but only processing certain nodes. One of the nodes is an attribute with multiple values separated by whitespace, and I want to break each of these values into a separate line in the target CSV file.

Sample source XML file:

```
<corpus>
 <deposition>
    <deposition-number n="dep1"/>
    <text>
      <seg n="seg1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <persName name="personA" ana="foo1 foo2">some foo person</persName> 
        adipiscing elit. Vivamu ultrices consequat facilisis. 
        Suspendisse a odio in lobortis. Aenean <persName name="personG" ana="foo2">some foo person</persName>
        non dui scelerisque, rutrum est at, cursus sem.</seg>
      <seg n="seg2">Ut pharetra <persName name="personF" ana="foo9">some foo person</persName>bibendum ipsum, portitor 
        velit pharetra quis. Aeneano purus. Praesent 
        aliquam viverra tellus.</seg>
     </text>
  </deposition>
  <deposition>
    <deposition-number n=""dep2"/>
    <text>
     <seg n="seg3">Curabitur pulvinar leo eget. Orci varius 
        natoque penatibus et magnis <persName name="personD" ana="foo2 foo3 foo8">some foo person</persName>montes, 
        nascetur ridiculus mus.</seg>
    </text>
  </deposition>
</corpus>
```

Currently I can output this unsatisfactory result in CSV, where `@ana` is in the final field:

```
 dep1~seg1~personA~foo1 foo2
 dep1~seg1~personG~foo2
 dep1~seg2~personF~foo9
 dep1~seg3~personD~foo2 foo3 foo8
```

With XSL that looks like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="persName">
        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::deposition-number/@n"/>
        <xsl:text>~</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::seg/@n"/>
        <xsl:text>~</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
        <xsl:text>~</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@ana"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

But I want to output this, where the `@ana` is parsed into distinct lines:

```
 dep1~seg1~personA~foo1
 dep1~seg1~personA~foo2
 dep1~seg1~personG~foo2
 dep1~seg2~personF~foo9
 dep1~seg3~personD~foo2
 dep1~seg3~personD~foo3
 dep1~seg3~personD~foo8
```

I've tried looking at tokenizing, but if it is able to solve this, I'm not sure how to do it. I don't know how to parse `@ana` and loop through it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this template instead, which uses `tokenize` to split up the attribute and output one row for each value

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//persName">
        <xsl:variable name="pers" select="." />
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(@ana, ' ')">
            <xsl:value-of select="$pers/ancestor::deposition/deposition-number/@n"/>
            <xsl:text>~</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$pers/ancestor::seg/@n"/>
            <xsl:text>~</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$pers/@name"/>
            <xsl:text>~</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

(Note that `deposition-number` is not an ancestor of `persName` in your XML)

Or, to simplify it a bit, try this...

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//persName">
        <xsl:variable name="pers" select="." />
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(@ana, ' ')">
            <xsl:value-of select="($pers/ancestor::deposition/deposition-number/@n, $pers/ancestor::seg/@n, $pers/@name, .)" separator="~"/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Brilliant, it worked perfect. I see the economy of the second, and will try it too. Thanks very much. (Also, my `deposition-number` was a typo, but I corrected for it)

Answer (score 2):

With XSLT 3 you can tokenize the values and push them to a template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//persName"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="persName">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="tokenize(@ana, '\s+')">
         <xsl:with-param name="data" select="ancestor::deposition/deposition-number/@n, ancestor::seg/@n, @name"/>
     </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match=".[. instance of xs:string]">
      <xsl:param name="data"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="$data, ." separator="~"/>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtpS/1

Comment: Does this solution provide a significant advantage in processing versus the nested `xsl:for-each` suggested by Tim C? (assume here that the document contains 10,000 instances of `persName` with each respective `@ana`  containing between 1 and 5 values) Thanks very much.

Comment: I feel more comfortable with decomposing the code into small templates but of course the approach of Tim (in particular the second sample that avoids all those `<xsl:text>~</xsl:text>`) does the job as well.